# Using random number generator with timer gives the same digit everytime in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, random

I am trying to make a text slide show with javascript, however in javascript the math floor function always returns the same random number. What is wrong with code below?

```
var randomnumber;
D=Array(7)
D[0]='Sunday!'
D[1]='Monday!'
D[2]='Tuesday!'
D[3]='Wednesday!'
D[4]='Thursday!'
D[5]='Friday!'
D[6]='Saturday!'

window.setTimeout("Tick()", 1000);    

function Tick() 
{
    document.write('<marquee><font size="+2">'+D[Math.floor(Math.random()*7)]+'</font></marquee>')    
}


</script>
```

Comment: *The marquee tag is a non-standard HTML element which causes text to scroll up, down, left or right automatically. The tag was first introduced in early versions of Microsoft's Internet Explorer, and was compared to Netscape's blink element, as a proprietary non-standard extension to the HTML standard with usability problems. It is deprecated by the W3C and not advised by them for use in any HTML documents* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/47f5X/). However, you must pass a reference to the function when using `setTimeout` and not a string. `setTimeout` uses an `eval`-like procedure when you pass it a string, making this method of usage unsafe.

```
function Tick() {...}

//pass a reference (no quotes)
window.setTimeout(Tick, 1000);​
```

---

`setTimeout` only fires once when the timeout is reached. If you want to do a constant, continuous `Tick`, then better use `setInterval` instead, which fires and "reloads" to fire again.

---

Here's [a modified version of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/47f5X/8/) to fit your description

```
//create the marquee and add to body 
var marquee = document.createElement('marquee');
document.body.appendChild(marquee);

function Tick() {
    //generate the random text
    var randomDay = D[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)];

    //change the existing marquee text
    //textContent for compliant browsers
    //innerText for IE
    marquee.textContent = randomDay;
}

//tick every second
window.setInterval(Tick, 1000);​
```

Comment: it doesn't work fine, it just keeps showing the same weekday all the time.

Comment: @HOY maybe you wanted to use setInterval?

Comment: @Joseph what do you mean by everytime you run it? It will run just 1 time, and in every timer tick, it must show a different day, but it is always the same?

Comment: @HOY because `setTimeout` is only fired once. You must have meant `setInterval` which in your case, [has weird effects](http://jsfiddle.net/47f5X/5/). You might want to change the way you print though.

Comment: @All, I don't see a difference when setInterval is used, result is same ?

Comment: @HOY I suppose you wanted to change the text every 1 second. The problem is you are printing a new set of text every time you call `Tick`. You are not changing the existing text. I updated my answer which might be the one you are looking for.

Comment: I want to reset the marquee tag with another text within the given time interval